# Disable Fast Web View on a PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, linearization

I've been trying to make PHP program to autofill PDF files using data from database using FPDF, but I get this error

> FPDF-Merge Error: Fast Web View mode is not supported

I've been looking for a free program that doesn't leave watermarks or modify the PDF that removes the Fast Web View, but couldn't find one. Is there any way that I could disable it?

Comment: TCPDF is a highly customizable PDF library and I approve this message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All valid linearized (Fast Web View) PDFs are also valid un-linearized PDFs, so it's hard to see why FPDF would complain - the worst it could do is produce an output file which is not linearized.

Our [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) tool can remove linearization easily:

```
cpdf in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

ought to do it.

Comment: +1 for the validity explanation. Refusing to operate on a pdf merely because of linearization is bad.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! But now I got an error 
FilterFlateDecode: invalid stream data.
(I am trying to fill PDF form automatically from PDF form using FPDM)
It has something to do with this code: http://pastebin.com/qiEB9BWs

I don't understand why data is set to null in this, but I am getting to a poing of giving up fpdm and looking for something better... Any ideas?

Comment: I explained my problem further in a new question  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766045/php-pdf-form-filling-using-fpdm-gives-error-filterflatedecode-invalid-stream-da). Thank you again for helping me solve this problem.