# Fill Form FDDF FPDF-Merge Error Fast Web View mode is not supported

Tags: php, fpdf

I try to use FPDF to fill pd form of this way

```
$pdf = new FPDM('Form.pdf');
```

but i get

```
FPDF-Merge Error: Fast Web View mode is not supported solution
```

PD:

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741208/disable-fast-web-view-on-a-pdf-file), Show this soution;

```
cpdf in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

but i don't know the process to use cpdf

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Go into the PDF in Adobe Acrobat.
Click Edit->Preferences
Go to Documents
Uncheck the 'Save As optimizes for Fast Web View'

Save the document.
That resolves that error for me.  After doing so, I received a compression error and needed to use pdftk to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but for anyone else having issue with this - I got this error after editing and saving pdf file that was already converted by pdftk.
The solution was to run it again through the pdftk

> pdftk 55.pdf output 555.pdf